# Cannot use folder-name field to filter resources in HP QC REST API

Tags: rest, url, hp-quality-center

I don't expect to get an answer on this but if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

We're using HP Application Lifecycle Management 12.2 (ALM or QC/QualityCenter as it's called). I'm trying to retrieve test resources from the project using the REST api but I suspect I've come across a defect in the API.

I'm trying to filter the response by using a query, and any other query works fine but when I try to use the 'folder-name' field it fails with the following message:

> Failed to set params in the parametrized query

It doesn't matter what format I try to escape the query with, I've tried the following:

`/resources/?query={folder-name[%27folder%27]}
/resources/?query={folder-name['folder']}
/resources/?query=%7bfolder-name%5b%27folder%27%5d%7d`

I've also reproduced this on an 11.52 QC instance so it's not just our environment. I've double checked the customization collection using the ?can-filter=true param and folder-name is supposed to be filterable.

I'm currently using the parent-id for filtering instead which works but it requires me to do another request to get the parent-id first which I would like to refrain from.

Any suggestions, patches?
Thanks

Comment: I came here because I got the same error message in another, more complex call. I just wanted to say that the error is reproducable here, and that I agree that it is strange. The folder-name exists as a field in resource, and should be filterable. It seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, the error is reproducable here, and I agree that it is strange. The folder-name exists as a field in resource, and should be filterable. It seems to be a bug.

But there is another approach that I offer as a substitute solution. The resource entity offer a relation directly to the folder entity, and you can get the exact result you were looking for, by using a cross join with that table:

```
/resources/?query={resource-folder.name['folder']}
```

This is probably too late to help you with your work, but it might help others.

Comment: btw, We are still on 11.52

Comment: Thank you for the input. As you said we've already moved over to another solution. We were using ALM to do stuff it wasn't designed for so my tip to anyone trying the same would be to not spend too much time on it, there are far too many time drains spread across the APIs. It's good for what it was made to do but it's easy to get tempted to build your own network of integrations around it.